# How to repeate custom field group with bulk image field

Tags: custom-field

I have a custom post type "Events" which contains events details. in this single event may happen in different places. So I want to disply custom fields "Location" and "Images" for the custom post. And I want to repeat this field group for adding multiple 'locations' and image uploader(Bulk image uploader) for each location..How can i do this?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

it need custom code to create repeatable fields but if you want ready-made solution than you may try this : https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2

just include it in your theme/plugin and than check it's example-functions.php file , it have example of repeatable fields :)

here is direct documentation link : http://cmb2.io/docs/field-types#-types-group

it also support many other fields .

Cheers !

Comment: Thanks for your responce.. i'll try with that and let you know.. :)